# Sell in only some cities woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, registration

In **my account** page,
I want to use a similar code as below to sell in a specific "cities" or "postcodes", the below code is used to sell in a specific "states":

```
/**
 * Sell only in Alger & Zeralda
 */

    function wc_sell_only_states( $states ) {
        $states['DZ'] = array(
            'ALG' => __( 'Alger', 'woocommerce' ),
            'ZLD' => __( 'Zeralda', 'woocommerce' ),
        );
        return $states;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_states', 'wc_sell_only_states' );
```

What shall I use or modify?

I tried this, but it displays "Error code 500":

```
// define the woocommerce_countries_base_city callback 
function filter_woocommerce_countries_base_city( $var ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    $var['DZ'] = array(
        'ALG' => __( 'Alger', 'woocommerce' ),
        'ZLD' => __( 'Zeralda', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    return $var; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries_base_city', 'filter_woocommerce_countries_base_city', 10, 1 );
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: The guys who found my question unclear or useful please tell me what's wrong with it?!

Comment: This is not a standard wocommerce hook, but part of a plugin for chilean peso? Here is a list of the standard WooCommerce hooks -> https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html

Comment: I found it here https://gist.github.com/woogist/b81742981ca6297b03e6 and it worked for me, now I need also to specify some cities only

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: No, not yet, I am still trying!

Comment: Why don't you post the code you did try?

Comment: I edited my question, you can find what code i tried

Answer (score 1):

Try This it worked for me!!

```
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_args', 'custom_form_field_args', 10, 3 );
            function custom_form_field_args( $args, $key, $value ) { 
                if ( $args['id'] == 'billing_city' ) {
                 $args = array(
                        'label' => __( 'Town / City', 'woocommerce' ),
                        'required' => TRUE,
                        'clear' => TRUE,
                        'type' => 'select',
                        'options' =>  array(
                            '' => ('Select City' ),
                    'Bangalore' => ('Bangalore' ),
                    'Mysore' => ('Mysore' )
                    ),
                        'class' => array( 'update_totals_on_change' )
                    );
                } // elseif … and go on 

                return $args;
            };
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide some explanation of what the code is doing and how it resolves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler solution to this. The approach also depends on the some assumption which are listed below:

Assumption : If there is only one City which you want the City field to be set to then you can use jQuery. Using jQuery you will be setting the value of the field and make the fields disabled to avoid change in City field value.

A rough example will be :

```
jQuery('#billing_city').val('USA').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

You just need to add this line such that it is execute on Checkout page.